# 'function' object has no attribute 'objects' Django

Tags: django, search, solr, django-haystack

I am using haystack and solr for searching but i am getting a error 'function' object has no attribute 'objects'

This is my search_indexes.py

```
from haystack import indexes
from haystack.indexes import SearchIndex
from jobpost.models import *
import site 


class JobIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    post_type = indexes.CharField(model_attr='post_type')
    location = indexes.CharField(model_attr='location')
    job_type = indexes.CharField(model_attr='job_type')
    company_name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='company_name')
    title = indexes.CharField(model_attr='title')

    def get_model(self):
        return jobpost

    def index_queryset(self,**kwargs):
        return self.get_model.objects.all()
```

and if i try to register it like this **site.register(jobpost, JobIndex)

it gives me error     from haystack import site
ImportError: cannot import name site

can anyone tell why is it so?

Comment: I think `get_model` is a method. So you have to call it first. Try `return self.get_model().objects.all()`

Comment: Which version of Haystack are you using? Site is deprecated in 2.0

Comment: @MadeehaAmeer Then read this: http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/migration_from_1_to_2.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get_model` is a method. So you have to call it first. Try

```
return self.get_model().objects.all()
```

Comment: getting another eroor 'Indexing 2 jobposts
Failed to add documents to Solr: [Reason: None]
<response><lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">400</int><int name="QTime">2231</int></lst><lst name="error"><str name="msg">ERROR: [doc=jobpost.jobpost.1] unknown field 'django_id'</str><int name="code">400</int></lst></response>
'

Comment: can u plz tell why it is adding it to solr?

Comment: Can't say anything without seeing the code. But this is a different problem. Feel free to open a new question and add some codes there. Will check.

Comment: If this solved your problem, accept it as answer please. So that future visitors know.